# Can I get 120 from a leg of 240 in this setup

Tags: wiring, 120-240v

Similar questions have been asked but not exactly.

This is a 240V fuse box that the air conditioner installers recently put in. It has 2 legs of 120 and a ground wire coming from the junction box.

Is there a straightforward way to get a 120 VAC connection from this fuse box without doing anything shady? I need this to connect a sprinkler timer--there are no functioning 120 outlets within 100 ft.

I know that I could cut the plug off the sprinkler timer cable, run it into the fuse box and tie it between one of the legs and ground. But I don't know how kosher that would be.

The 3 photos below illustrate my setup.

Edit to address some of the comments:

I added 2 pictures of the back of the junction box. It appears to have a safety ground screwed to it. I also checked continuity between the green wire (apparently connected to neutral) and the safety ground of a plug in the house. This neutral wire is not isolated from ground. It is shorted.

I also got a picture of the inside of the fuse box door, with a bonus shot of my shiny head.

[image: Fuse Box]

[image: Junction Box]

[image: Both]

[image: BackLeft][image]

[image: Shiny]

Comment: What's behind that hole in the wall? conduit, or something else? Any chance you could pull an additional wire into that junction box?

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the inside front door label? It references ground and neutral and may be critical to figuring this out.

Comment: Can you get us a photo clearly showing the back of the box the conduit run originates in, please?

Comment: @LShaver: All I can say for sure is junction box with apparent safety ground connected. See added photos

Comment: @ manassehkattz: You were sure right about that. I added a photo.

Comment: @ ThreePhaseEel: Yes. added.

Comment: At first read, this thing is choc-a-bloc with code violations.  Why not use or tap the existing 120V outlet that Code absolutely requires to be installed near the air conditioning unit (so the installer can run a vampire pump to recover coolant)?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- because that 120V serviceperson's outlet is nowhere to be found...

Comment: @mtp -- can you post a photo of the nameplate on your A/C's outdoor unit please?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica was just having this discussion... where in the code would I find this requirement?

Comment: @LShaver NEC 210.63.

Comment: Can you find anywhere inside where that original cable jacket can be seen?  I want to know a) what the insulating jacket type is (UF, NM, SE, SE-R, several possibilities), b) whether it is copper or aluminum, and c) the wire size in AWG.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done not even a tough conversion.

I would make some minor changes and change that outside box into a breaker panel.

A simple 4 slot nema R3 (outside rated) would work.

You have a real ground in the back of the box.

Make sure that neutral is going to the main panel along with the ground. .

This new sub panel allows for your breaker and disconnect right there outside.

The other breaker is for the service receptacle.
Now that there is a breaker that is a separate circuit according to code.

I have this same setup but I have lockouts on my 2 double pole breakers so no disconnects are required as my breakers having lockouts are legal.

My systems were installed prior to 240v requiring GFCI you will need a double pole GFCI to meet current code if on 2021 NEC.

GFCI receptacle & heavy duty cover. In a bell box create your service receptacle.

The white is the neutral. The black & red are hot and the ground is ground. On the sub the neutral has to be isolated

That’s not only how I would do it but how I have done it at my personal home and customers, a small sub and GFCI breaker.
No need to run 100’ of wire.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of different issues involved:

#### Is that Ground or Neutral?

Green = Ground. Not two ways around that. However, in the wall junction you have white (**neutral**) connecting to the green that goes to this disconnect. Assuming the wiring is: Panel inside the wall -> wall junction -> fuse box -> A/C, then the green wires here are actually neutral! Which is a very good thing.

If indeed these green wires are *actually* neutral, then you should be able to switch them for **white** wires (both the short piece to the wall junction and a longer piece to the A/C). In addition, there may be a change in how the wires are connected inside this box - it is **not** clear and we need additional details, such as the full label from the door, to figure that out.

If the installers used green here because they *don't* need neutral for the A/C but do need ground, then the (a) you can add a separate white neutral wire and (b) connect the green wire at the junction box to an actual ground wire.

The good news is that your wires are in conduit. So adds/changes are not a big deal. The really good news is that your wires are in *metal* conduit. If that is the case end-to-end and installed properly then you likely do not need any ground wires at all and can safely *replace* green with white instead of having to add a totally new wire.

#### Can you add to this circuit?

Generally speaking, a large installed appliance (like an air conditioner) has a circuit of its own. Adding a small additional 120V load (like the sprinkler timer) may or may not be permitted, depending on the size of the loads, the size of the circuit and the instructions provided with the sprinkler timer.

On the other hand, your wires are in conduit. You can probably (depends on conduit size) simply add an additional hot/neutral pair of wires to the same conduit, connect them to a separate breaker (typically 15A or 20A) in the panel and connect them to the sprinkler timer.

---

Update based on additional details in Question:

This appears to be a [DiversiTech DDS-30](https://www.diversitech.com/en-US/item/id/14775) or similar.

As I understand the label, it is referring to use of this disconnect box as "Service Equipment" - i.e., the first box after the meter as a disconnect/master fuse. In that situation, like a typical "main panel", neutral and ground are one and the same.

However, when used any place else, ground and neutral need to be kept totally separate.

In this particular case, it **appears** that the middle screws with the green wires are (a) for ground, not neutral and (b) bonded to the case. If that's true, then it should **not** be used for neutral. An ordinary shutoff/disconnect doesn't need to bother with neutral - neutral gets to just pass through.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find much additional information on the DiversiTech site. My hunch - but hopefully an HVAC pro or electrician can confirm - is the following:

- The box requires ground but does not require neutral.
- Since it is a metal box and metal conduit, ground can be provided via the conduit itself, but *can* be done using green wire.
- The green wire absolutely should **not** be connected to the white wire (in the wall junction box).
- The green wire (unless removed) should be connected with a screw to the wall junction box to provide a continuous ground and must be disconnected from the white wire.
- If the HVAC actually needs a neutral (i.e., has any 120V components) then a white wire should be connected to the white wire in the wall junction box and pass through (either as one long wire or split and joined with a wire nut in the disconnect box) the disconnect box to the HVAC equipment.
- If the green is connected to anything other than ground/metal case on the HVAC equipment then it needs to be disconnected.

The way to tell for sure whether the HVAC actually needs a neutral connection is model #s or wiring diagram.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer. Please see my updates when you have a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Fuggedaboutit, for a bunch of reasons. But let's start with the deal killer.

### You can't put a receptacle on a dedicated hardwired appliance circuit

Anytime you have a large appliance circuit like that, with a hardwired load, you cannot fit receptacles on that circuit **if the hardwired load accounts for more than 50% of circuit ampacity**. *And it always does because large appliances are expected to have dedicated circuits*.

So it wouldn't even matter if the receptacle was 240V.

It's too bad your thing isn't 240V *and hardwired*... if so it could share this circuit.

### It's moot anyway, because of the next change you must make.

Since you said this is recent work, it must comply with recent codes which  **require** a 120V convenience receptacle near the heat pump unit.  As discussed above, this must be on a separate circuit.

This is normally done as part of the normal outdoor receptacle wiring that houses are supposed to/obliged to have.

So once you correct that deficiency, you can plug your appliance in there.

### ... and there's an easy way to do that.

EDIT: OK, so I had it wrong.  I thought you had conduit; you actually have a 4-conductor cable.  But "It's still good!" the cost just went up a little bit.

You need an air conditioning disconnect right where you have one.  Fusing isn't required, but it is allowed.  A funny thing about a **subpanel* - while it is many things, **it is also a disconnect**.

So since you have 4 wires coming here, we need to change that A/C disconnect out to be a sub panel.  That will allow us to support both the air conditioner and the required 120V receptacle.

3 breaker spaces needed - 2 for the A/C and 1 for the 120V receptacle.  Note that you could get this done with a "2-space, 4-circuit" panel, using a 30/20 quadplex.  Or you could go with a larger panel, like a 6-space, 12-space or even 40-space... it's completely at your discretion.  I would think about the size of the supply wires vs the size of the loads, think about what else you could support out here, and "err on the large side".  Let's presume 6-space.

The sub panel must have isolated neutral and ground, and its own ground bus.

---

How to make that work at the wall surface? Fairly straightforward.  Get an outdoor rated "extension box" that bolts over top of the existing box using the existing mounting screws.., and has 1/2" knockouts or fittings on the side.

Replace the one conduit with *two* conduits that go straight into the side of the extension box.  One for the feeder to the sub panel, the other to come back to serve a receptacle (or two) mounted in the extension box.

Extend hots, neutral and ground from this box to the sub panel's two hot lugs, neutral lug and ground lug. The hots+neutral must be in the same conduit. Safety ground can go through the other conduit, since it doesn't normally carry current.

As far as wire size, see my followup question about type, metal and size of old cable in the walls.

Now, hook up the A/C 2 hots to the breaker, and ground to the ground bar.

Now, get black, white, green #12 THHN, fit a receptacle in the extension box, and run to the 15A breaker, neutral and ground. Use the conduit that the #8 feeder did not use.

In fact,  you could use a 2-gang extension box, and fit two receptacles side by side (in a domed cover).  They could each be on different 120V circuits, since you can have up to 4 circuits in the pipe that is not being used by the feeder.

Comment: I suspect that that *is* a cable (you can see the jacket on it in the very last shot), but a SER type cable, which means they could quite readily fit a subpanel in place of the A/C disconnect...

Comment: That would be much better.  How about you take that one? :)

Comment: That cable looks a lot bigger than the wires going to/from the disconnect. So if the wires to/from the disconnect are 10 AWG then the cable has to be at least 8 AWG - upbreaker and subpanel.